# how to check multiple condition while using group by statements in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

BOOK_ADOPTION (course:int, sem:int, book_isbn:int)

TEXT (book_isbn:int, booktitle: varchar(50), publisher: varchar(50), author: varchar(50))

List the books which are adopted by the course as well as enrolled by the student.

I am trying this:

```
select course 
from text 
natural join book_adoption 
group by course 
having count(book_isbn)>1 
  and publisher = 'perason';
```

and getting an error:

> Unknown column 'publisher' in 'having clause'

but the column publisher is there and even the spelling is correct.
Can someone help me out with this one?

Comment: I don't exactly understood your problem but, you haven't specified `ON` which column to join `text` and `book_adoption`. For your error you must prefix width table name or alias. Like `text.publisher`

Comment: Column name used in HAVING without aggregate function is output list column. But your output does not contain `publisher` column. Maybe move this condition to WHERE?

Comment: @Akina oh yeah. Got it, my mistake.

Comment: @VivekMakwana `natural join` does join on columns with equal names, so it doesn't require `on`. It should be avoided, because it hides original intent in case of schema evolution, but still valid in terms of ANSI compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAVING clause is for using with aggregating functions (like count) but in the case of publisher you have to simply use the WHERE condition.

```
select course
from text natural join book_adoption 
where publisher = 'perason'
group by course 
having count(book_isbn)>1;
```